# Python logic - Euler 62

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to learn python by solving problem from projecteuler.net. I've been trying to solve problem 62, but I can't find where I am going wrong. The problem states thus:

```
The cube, 41063625 (345^3), can be permuted to produce two other cubes: 56623104 (384^3) and 66430125 (405^3). 
In fact, 41063625 is the smallest cube which has exactly three permutations of its digits which are also cube.
Find the smallest cube for which exactly five permutations of its digits are cube.
```

My logic for solving this problem:
- generate cubes for up to 10000 and store them in a set
- for each cube in the set (starting from the biggest), find the max number that can be formed using the digits in the number. If two cubes have the same digits, they will form the same max number.
- store these max numbers in another set. If the max number is already in that set, increment a counter corresponding to that max number.
- if the counter is 5, stop.

Here is the code I wrote for implementing the above logic. It gives me an answer of 140283769536, but it is not the right answer. Where am I going wrong?

```
def maxperm(number):
    maxnum=0
    digits=[0 for x in range(10)]
    while number>0:
        digits[number%10]+=1
        number/=10
    numdigits=sum(digits)
    for i in range(9,-1,-1):
        if digits[i]>0:
            for x in range(digits[i]):
                numdigits-=1
                maxnum+=i*10**numdigits
    return maxnum

uniquecubes=dict()
cubes=[x**3 for x in range(10000)]
cubeset=set(cubes)
maxperms=set()

for i in reversed(cubes):
    a=maxperm(i)
    if a in maxperms:
        uniquecubes[a]+=1
        if uniquecubes[a]==5:
            print i
            break
    else:
        uniquecubes[a]=1
        maxperms.add(a)
```

Comment: I suspect your algorithm is wrong. There are two things I can think of. 1: there is a sixth cube with those digits (unlikely). 2: you have not chosen the smallest of the 5 cubes (but one of the other four). Alternatively, maybe `maxperm` is broken? Does your algorith give the correct result for the simple case?

Comment: Looking better at your algorithm: it may indeed be the case that there is a smaller solution. Try working upwards from 1, instead of downwards from a large-ish number.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, I checked maxperm - it does give correct results. if I work upwards, I would end up with the biggest cube, right? that's why I wanted to start from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is designed to find if 5 *minimum* permutations exist that are also cubes, which is not the problem asked.

Solution 1: modify the algorithm to check if a 6th exists, and if it does, trash the answer and keep looking.

Solution 2 (preferred): Have a function `permCheck()` that takes a cube, creates every permutation of that cube's digits, and returns how many of those permutations are also cubes. Once you have that:

```
int i = 1
while True:
    if permCheck(i*i*i) == 5:
        break
    i += 1
return i*i*i  # i^3 is now the answer
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that there was only one cube that had 5 permutations that were also cubes. Turns out there was one other. I removed the break and appended all the results into a list and extracted the minimum from the list.